# container .fadeIn/Out with HighCharts and Leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts, leaflet

So I have 2 wrappers one that has a highchart and the other one has a leaflet map. Im using buttons to toggle the divs in and out. The chart div works fine but the map one I have to click the the button twice to get it to render. I tried to put a `setTimer()` to see if would help with the transition but nothing. I have a fiddle that illustrates what Im trying to do but its having an issue with the map [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QBYPH/1/). My question is why it wont render right away? and What can I do to make it render right away? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rendering the `chart` in `container` and the `container` has both the `map` and `chart` so after rendering the `chart` your `map div` removed from `container` so it creates problem.

**Note:** you have given `container id` to `div` twice

Replace your **HTML** like

```
<div id="maincontainer">
    <div id="chart-wrapper" style="display:block; overflow: auto;">
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
    </div>
  <div id="map-wrapper" style="overflow: auto; display: none;">
        <div id="map-container" style="height: 400px; "></div>
    </div>
</div>


<button id="toggle-btn">Map</button>
<button id="run-btn">run</button>
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QBYPH/2/